# Stimulus Check Eligibility (College Student)

Tags: united-states, check, stimulus

If I am a 19 yr old college student with a part time job and currently unemployed due to the virus outbreak, will I be eligible for the stimulus check? I did not submit a tax return in 2018, but I did submit my 2019 tax return a month ago already, so I believe they will go off of my 2019 tax return. My parents claimed me as a dependent on their tax returns.

Will I be able to receive as $1200 stimulus check?

Comment: You may have to wait for an answer until the bill actually becomes law. It passed the senate but could still get held up or revised in the house. At this point everything is conjecture and hear-say until we get the actual text of the bill.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for speculation about possible future law

Comment: Update: Trump has just signed it into law, so it is now no longer speculative.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that on your 2019 tax return, you checked the box that said "Someone can claim: You as a dependent". (If not, then either you or your parents filed incorrectly.) In this case, you cannot receive the stimulus check.

If nobody can claim you as a dependent (i.e. nobody meets the conditions to claim you, not just that they choose not to claim you) for 2020, and your 2020 AGI is less than $99,000, you will still be able to claim the stimulus payment as a credit against your 2020 taxes.

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the same boat as you, and it does appear we will not get the stimulus check. My mother told me if I paid her the $1400 dollars she received claiming me as a dependent she would remove me as a dependent on her 2019 tax return.......so that I could get the $1200 check. I think the only way to change this is if we pound our senators and congressmen on twitter until they realize they left out millions of college students. I don't get support from my parents and didn't realize how much money they've made off claiming me as a dependent these last 4 years of college.

Comment: Do you have a source to support the assertion in your answer?

Comment: If you receive no (financial) support from your parents then they should not legally be claiming you as a dependent.

Comment: "she would remove me as a dependent on her 2019 tax return.......so that I could get the $1200 check" Eligibility for the payment is based on whether you *can be* claimed as a dependent by someone else, not whether they actually claim you. So as long as you *can be* claimed as a dependent by your mom (which is true if she has a choice to claim you or not), you are not eligible for the payment, even if she does not actually claim you.

Answer (score -1):

i’m no expert, but there may be a catch. for the years 2018-2025, there is no longer a personal deduction. they should get zero for claiming dependents, and one would hope ppl should not be disqualified from receiving the check in that case. the language of the bill says something about if a person’s deduction could be claimed by another beginning in the calendar year of the taxable year. dont know what it means, but it might apply only if the 2018 taxable year is used as it began in 2017 before the deduction was eliminated. if its based on 2019 tax returns hoping it doesnt apply! -everyone- else apparently gets it except illegal aliens!

Comment: the issue for us college students is in the line pertaining to our parents claiming us as a dependent. Its worded in a way that I don't understand completely.

Comment: "they should get zero for claiming dependents" There is a $2000 child tax credit for each dependent child, and a $500 tax credit for each dependent who does not qualify for the child tax credit, assuming they make less than $400k (if filed jointly) or $200k (if filed separately).